# Need help for a parsing array imageicon into JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, compiler-errors, imageicon

this is the code i am having error with:

```
pic = new ImageIcon("Koala.jpg");
picArr = ImageUtil.sliceImage(3, 3, pic);
for (int i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++){
   leftbut[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(picArr[i]));            
}
```

This is the exact line of error:

```
leftbut[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(picArr[i]));
```

This is the error:

```
no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(ImageIcon)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(byte[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument ImageIcon cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(byte[],String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(Image) is not applicable
  (actual argument ImageIcon cannot be converted to Image by method invocation conversion)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(Image,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(URL) is not applicable
  (actual argument ImageIcon cannot be converted to URL by method invocation conversion)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(URL,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(String) is not applicable
  (actual argument ImageIcon cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
constructor ImageIcon.ImageIcon(String,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Additional info - leftbut.[i] is array of 9 buttons and i want to set imageicon on each one of them by using the above method and slicing the 1 image into 9 peices Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: 1) What is the error? Copy/paste it as an edit.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (complete, with no 3rd party APIs).

Answer (score 4):

this

`leftbut[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(picArr[i]));`

should be this

`leftbut[i].setIcon(picArr[i]);`